# nativewind (tailwindcss in react native) className=text-red-500 does not work without wrapping it with flex

Tags: javascript, react-native, tailwind-css

Just started tutorial of a react native project and had to follow nativewind document to setup tailwindcss as the instructor followed the deprecated version, now my question is the following code doesn't make the text red

```js
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <View >
          <Text className="text-red-500">
            Open up App.js to start working on your app!
          </Text>
          <StatusBar />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

And the following code displays the text in red,

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-white">
      <Text className="text-red-500">
        Open up App.js to start working on your app!
      </Text>
      <StatusBar />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**So Why do we need to have flex-1 in the View className to have text-red-500 in Text work?**

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing like text-red in tailwind, it should be text-rose-500

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).